# How to set properties of an object immediately in matlab GUI?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a status-reporting code that is within a callback function of a push-button in a custom matlab gui:

```
function gathering_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 set(handles.status,'string','Viewer is processing your data, please wait...');
 some function that take time...();
 set(handles.status,'string','Process completed!');
```

The problem is the first set function does not call immediately- it waits until the whole block executes so we don't see first text (because of the second text).

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Try [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html)

Comment: Thank you very much excaza! it worked and my problem solved